# for-loop behaviour changing from seemingly unrelated code

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, arduino

The code example is used to create a binary counter using a row of LEDs. I was checking out an online tutorial that issued this as a challenge. My goal was to do this in a way that is scalable.

The below code is functioning, but I have an issue. Within the setup function, I call the Serial.begin function which I was using for logging while writing the code. As it is, the code loops through from 0 to 16, flashing the correct corresponding LED.

When I remove the Serial.begin line, the loop breaks, but at a weird point. It goes all the way through to 16 once (ie all 4 LEDs lit) and then it loops back around, and then gets stuck flashing just the one LED (indicating 1). The puzzling thing to me is obviously since the loop starts at 0, it's actually going through to the second iteration of the loop when it fails.

I'm not otherwise using any other Serial functions and since it works with Serial.begin, I feel like it's mathematically sound. It's leading me to think this is something Arduino specific and I'd really like to understand what's happening here to produce the different results.

I'm also new to C++ and Arduino in general, so general advice or feedback is also appreciated!

```
/*
 * The following code runs an Arduino powering 4 LEDs counting in binary
 * Mission was to do this dynamically using for-loops, so that it is scalable for adding say, more LEDs
 * To add an LED, all one needs to do is update the variable 'bits', increase the size of the 'ledArray' and 'myArray' and assign Arduino pins to the new LEDs 
 */

// using Arduino pins 3, 5, 6 & 9. While I'm using PWM pins, this code uses digital write and there's no need to stick to these for the purpose of this code
int led1 = 3; 
int led2 = 5;
int led3 = 6;
int led4 = 9;
int bits = 4; // the number of bits AKA the number of LEDs in the circuit
int del = 350; // the interval for each flash
int topNumber = pow(2,bits); // define the decimal number that can be counted to on a given set. 
int ledArray[4] = {led1, led2, led3, led4}; // this array is made up of the Arduino pins. The array size should be the same as the number of bits
int myArray[4] = {0}; // this array is the array that creates the binary string. The array size should be the same as the number of bits

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Getting some odd behaviour with this :/ originally here for troubleshooting
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led4, OUTPUT);  
}

void loop() {    
 // the following for-loop iterates each number in the set from 0 to the ceiling (topNumber) 
  for (int n = 0; n <= topNumber; n++) {     

    int tempValue = n; // set a temporary variable for n - we're going to manipulate n to format our binary, but we want to come back to this value before this loop concludes to increment on it

    // the following for-loop builds an array to present the binary string eg 1,0,0,1 for 1001
      for (int i = 0; n > 0; i++) {
        myArray[i] = n % 2;
        n /= 2;        
      }     

    // the following for-loop matches the leds in the ledArray with the binary array and sets the voltage high as required
      for (int i = 0; i <= bits; i++) {
        if(myArray[i] == 1) {            
          digitalWrite(ledArray[i], HIGH);     
        } else {
        }      
      }      

      delay(del);

    // the following for-loop iterates through the ledArray and switches them all off after completion
      for (int i = 0; i <= bits; i++) {
        digitalWrite(ledArray[i],LOW);
      }

      n = tempValue; // return n to its original value so that the for-loop will iterate as intended

    }
}
```

Comment: Loop condition `i <= bits` suppose to be `i <bits`. Out of bound array access is happening

Comment: Thanks for that, you're definitely right about that. Even after correcting that issue though I'm getting this same problem behaviour which the presence of `Serial.begin(9600);` seems to be implicated in

Comment: It's hard tell the cause without looking at [minimum reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

n <= topNumber should be n < topNumber.

Here's what the as-written code does:
topNumber = 2 raised to the 4th power, that is 16. 16 in binary is 10000; note that that uses 5 bits rather than 4. When the loop()'s for() loop reaches n = 16, it writes into myArray[4], which doesn't exist.

Because C and C++ don't protect against out of bounds array accesses, that loop writes a value into some other place in memory. My guess is that adding or removing the Serial.begin() line likely rearranges memory a little, which changes the effect of writing into that non-existent myArray[4].

One C language thing you probably know: arrays declare the number of items in the array; not the index of the last member of the array. So myArray[4] declares an array with myArray[0], myArray[1], myArray[2], and myArray[3]. There is no myArray[4].